# Transiting in the US with a soon-to-expire passport?

Tags: usa, passports, layovers

I am holding a HKSAR passport and am currently residing in Canada. I am travelling back home this November and had my tickets bought. I am having a layover in Seattle during my way back to Hong Kong. My passport, however, is expiring by the end of the year. I understand that for normal travelling I will need to have at least 6 months validity on my passport before I can entre the States. Does this also apply to layover flights?

I am hoping to renew my passport once I arrive home in Hong Kong but if I am not allowed to board then I will need to figure something out.

Comment: probably you need a USA transit visa as well, am I right?

Answer (score 6):

Rules in the US are usually the same for layover/transit and for entering the country so I don't think the fact that you would be transiting exempts you from any passport validity requirement.

In your case, however, it seems [Hong Kong is on the list](http://www.state.gov/documents/organization/104770.pdf) of countries whose citizens can enter the US even if their passport expires less than six months after their intended date of departure. It should therefore be possible to transit with your soon-to-expire passport (and a visa).

See also [How long does my passport have to be valid for a layover in the US?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21075/how-long-does-my-passport-have-to-be-valid-for-a-layover-in-the-us?rq=1)

Comment: That list seems to contain almost all countries, is there a list which contains the opposite?

Comment: @AdityaSomani Unlikely... that would get into the whole "what is recognized as a country" issue...